# Detect closing braces with a command

Tags: conditionals, braces

I want to make a command that detects if the next token written in the document is a closing brace.

My best approach is to use the `\@ifnextchar` command. In fact, the following code:

```
\makeatletter
{
\@ifnextchar{\egroup}{yes}{no}
}
\makeatother
```

Does print `yes`. But when i try to define a command `\demo` in a `.sty` file as:

```
\newcommand{\demo}
{
\@ifnextchar{\egroup}{yes}{no}
}
```

and make the call:

```
{\demo}
```

It prints `no`. I suppose that this happens because LaTeX detects a "end of command" token before returning to the document. Anyway, I would like to know the actual reason of why this happens, and how should I define the `\demo` command for printing `yes` in the last example.

edit:

In a blank document it actually prints yes. This is my minimal working example where it prints no:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\wrapper}{ >{\SplitList{.}} m }
{
\begin{itemize}
\ProcessList{#1}{\entry}
\end{itemize}
}

\newcommand{\entry}[1]
{
\item \begin{math} #1 \end{math}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\demo}{\@ifnextchar{\egroup}{yes}{no}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\wrapper{a.b.{\demo}.d} prints no
but {\demo} prints yes


\end{document}
```

edit 2:

I just noticed that in my project, detecting that `\demo` is the last one within a `\wrapper` could be enough. So:

```
\wrapper{\demo.\demo}
```

should print `no` first and then `yes`. Now that I look at it this way, I'm sure it has to be another way to get this information easier.

Comment: I get `yes`. Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: (a) Your real world macro `\demo` should not contain any code between `\@ifnextchar` with its three arguments and the end of the macro. Otherwise `\@ifnextchar` would just see the first token of the code. (b) `\@ifnextchar` gobbles following spaces (for example, the space in the definition by the line end). If spaces matter, then `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` of package `ltxmcds` can be used.

Comment: The braces around `\demo` are stripped off by effect of `\SplitList`.

Comment: A much slower routine needs to be used if you don't want the braces are stripped off. Can you tell why you want to do this?

Comment: It's surely possible to detect if something is at the end of the split list. But it's still unclear why you want this check: knowing the reason may give better ideas.

Comment: `\wraper{a.b.{}{\demo}.d}` or `\wrapper{a.b.{{\demo}}.d}`

Comment: @egreg Looking at the documentation for `\SplitList` it's not clear to me how you would know that the brackets are stripped away.  Could you point me in the right direction so I can understand why I should know this?

Comment: @egreg Giving a full example of how would I use this `\demo` is preety complicated. How can I know if I'm in the last element of a `\SplitList`? If I can't make it work with it I'll post my whole code

Comment: @A.Ellett That's a general TeX feature: when arguments are grabbed (delimited or undelimited) a pair of braces is stripped off unless, in the delimited case, they would leave unbalanced braces.

Comment: @egreg That much I understand, but in splitting it isn't clear (to me) that the brackets should be removed.  I dug into the `xparse` code.  The stripping of brackets seems to be happening when the `\SplitList` gets to `\seq_set_split:Nnn` for which such stripping is documented.  How can a recommendation be made to those in charge of `xparse` that a similar comment be made in the documentation to `\SplitList`?  Or are you suggesting that because this is happening in a context of argument parsing, I should assume such stripping of brackets is already occurring?

Comment: @A.Ellett Yes, that's the place where the brace stripping off takes place. Maybe the documentation of `xparse` should point this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is that `\demo` prints `yes` if it's the last item in the list, then this should work:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrapper}{ m }
 {
  \begin{itemize}
  \azpillaga_wrapper:n { #1 }
  \end{itemize}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\demo}{ }
 {
  \azpillaga_demo:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__azpillaga_input_seq
\tl_new:N \l__azpillaga_last_tl
\bool_new:N \l__azpillaga_last_item_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azpillaga_wrapper:n #1
 {
  \bool_set_false:N \l__azpillaga_last_item_bool
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__azpillaga_input_seq { . } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__azpillaga_input_seq \l__azpillaga_last_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__azpillaga_input_seq { \entry{##1} }
  \bool_set_true:N \l__azpillaga_last_item_bool
  \entry {\tl_use:N \l__azpillaga_last_tl }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \azpillaga_demo:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l__azpillaga_last_item_bool
   {
    yes
   }
   {
    no
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\entry}[1]
{
\item \begin{math} #1 \end{math}
}

\begin{document}

Not at the end:
\wrapper{a.b.\demo.d}

At the end:
\wrapper{\demo.\demo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitively a working answer. It's important to keep my document free of `expl3` syntax. Can someone build an alternative?

Comment: @MartinAzpillaga If you use `xparse` you have `expl3` anyway.

Comment: At this moment, I know nothing about `expl3`. As I mentioned above, this code is part of a more complicated structure which I would be unable to switch to `expl3` right now. If I can't get a non-`expl3` answer, I'll probably post a new question with the whole structure so a full restructuring can be made.

Comment: Sorry, you can't do this with `xparse` only.

Comment: Then I think this is the best answer. Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

Though this has already been answered by @egreg , here's a solution that *superficially* avoids `expl3`:  as already mentioned by `egreg`, since `xparse` is built on `expl3` there really is no avoiding it.

If all you want to do is to be able to detect whether `\demo` has been passed as the last item in a list, this should work:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\def\mylastitem{\relax}

\NewDocumentCommand\wrapper{ m }
  {\ae@wrapper{#1\mylastitem}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ae@wrapper}{ >{\SplitList{.}} m }
{\begin{itemize}
 \ProcessList{#1}{\entry}
 \end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\entry}[1]{\item \begin{math} #1 \end{math}}

\newcommand\demo{\@ifnextchar\mylastitem{\textit{yes}}{\textit{no}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\wrapper{acd.b.{\demo}.d} prints \textit{no}

\wrapper{acd.b.c.\demo} prints \textit{yes}

\end{document}
```

However, I should point out that the community here will most likely frown on this sort of approach since I'm mixing the older style `@` notation with an implicit `expl3` style package.  Nevertheless, if you still feel the need to know how to get this to work without having to actually write `expl3` code yourself, the above should do the trick for you.